# WPF Style Triggers for DataTemplates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I would like to set Triggers for the controls in a `DataTemplate`. Whenever I set a property of the control within the `DataTemplate`, it seems not working. However, If do not set the property within the `TextBlock` inside the `DataTemplate`, then I can see the effect of `Trigger` in the style (it works). I am not sure whether using Style Triggers with `DataTemplate` is good or not! The XAML is below;

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="BlockOf">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold" />
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
                </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>
```

...........

DataTemplate for the button,

```xml
<Button.ContentTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="Button">
        <TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource BlockOf}" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}"
FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="9"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Button.ContentTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see two problems here. First one is that current trigger will work only for `TextBlock` inside `Button`, not over whole `Button`. You can change that by using `DataTrigger` with `RelativeSource` binding. Second problem is that even when mouse is over `TextBlock` `Style.Trigger` cannot overwrite local value that you set against `TextBlock` so you need to bring default values as `Setter` into your `Style`. Check [Dependency Property Setting Precedence List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx#listing)

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="BlockOf">
    <Setter Property="FontStyle" Value="Italic"/>
    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="9"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Button}}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="ExtraBold" />
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="22" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

and then `TextBlock` simply

```
<TextBlock Style="{DynamicResource BlockOf}" Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Content}" />
```

Comment: " First one is that current trigger will work only for TextBlock inside Button, not over whole Button", that's what I want. I just want to use IsMouseOver for the TextBlock inside the button. However, for the second problem I think you are right. So in order to work with Style Triggers, I should avoid local values and set them via Style Setters for ex., right?

Comment: Sorry, I just assumed it's wrong. If that's desired behaviour then your trigger is fine just don't set local values